# Root password Intel Edison

Tags: yocto, intel-edison

I'm trying to change the password for Intel-Edison board, using the Yocto project.

I have made a recipe for this.

```
#
# 'abc-' password
#
DESCRIPTION = "ROOT PASSWORD"
SECTION = "abc"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = 
"file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=xyz"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://test.txt"


PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P hello root;"

do_install() {
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/test.txt ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

To check if it works I added a file in my /etc/ location.
Everything is working perfectly , but my password remains 'root' . It should be 'hello'.
What I am doing wrong? Can someone tell me what should I do more?
Thank you.

Comment: Manual I have tells among other paragraphs *-p, --password PASSWORD
           The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).*

Comment: You mean like this: EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p  --encrypted_pass root;"  ?

Comment: Perhaps, what I was trying to tell is that my manual doesn't know anything about `-P`.